# Filter dataframe in R for rows that contain only NA and/or a number

Tags: r

I have data on how several school districts plan to spend money in various categories. NA means the school is not planning to spend money in that category, while an "X" or "$ -" or "######" means the school is planning to spend money, but has not specified how much. I want to filter my data so it only includes districts that explicitly stated how much they want to spend in each category, so there can be an NA or a number, but no other characters within any of the columns related to spending categories.

This is what I tried to do:

```
#Sample data

district_name <- c("District A","District B","District C","District D")
x <- c(5,10,4,5)
y <- c(10,"X",NA,999)
z <- c(NA,30,"$ - ",NA)
df_test <- data.frame(district_name, x,y,z)

#Try to convert all the NAs to zeros, then all non-numerics to NA, then remove the NAs. 

df_test[is.na(df_test)] = 0
df_test[,2:4] = as.numeric(df[,2:4])
df_test[!is.na(df_test[,2:4]), ]
```

However, I got this error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_test %>%
   filter(if_all(x:z,  ~ is.na(.x)|str_detect(.x, "^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$"))) %>% 
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
  district_name x   y  z
1    District A 5  10 NA
2    District D 5 999 NA
```

---

The error in OP's post is based on applying `as.numeric` on a data.frame, which requires a vector as input i.e. it can be done in a loop

```
df_test[2:4] <- lapply(df_test[2:4], as.numeric)
```

Comment: Thank you, lapply worked for me. Str_detect did not work as I also had some values that included decimals. I tried "^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$" as the regex but the escape key was not recognized.

Comment: @user3710004 try the updated regex.  The escape needs two `\\`

Comment: As an update to my original question: Later I found that in my data I need to replace $ - with 0. I tried df_test <- str_replace(df_test, "$ -", "0") as well as 
df_test %>% mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "$ -", "0"))). However, neither option worked. What should I do?

Comment: YOu can use `df_test %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ str_replace(.x, fixed("$ -"), "0")))`